# LitElement rendering template without values

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-element

I've got a simple example demonstrating what I'm seeing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-example-3pdnwk?file=index.js.

Basically when the first child element renders, the `text` property is set correctly. However on the second render, the `text` property is `undefined` first and then updated to be the correct value.

This breaks being able to depend on `_firstRendered()` to have the correct values assigned to the properties.

Am I doing something really off here?

Update: Here is a better example using a similar method provided in the [lit-html documentation](https://polymer.github.io/lit-html/guide/writing-templates.html#conditionals-ifs-and-loops): https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-issue?file=index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue as of `0.6.0-dev.5`

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something really off here?

maybe? :) Hopefully you can help me to understand why you chose your implementation and I can look into it further.

The part I'm stuck on is why you create and replace the child element inside the parent element like this:

```
this._child = html`<child-element text="${text1}"></child-element>`;
```

From what I understand so far, that code uses a lit-html helper function to create a [lit-html TemplateResult](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/master/docs/api/classes/_lit_html_.templateresult.html). You then replace it with another one in the timeout callback:

```
this._child = html`<child-element text="${text2}"></child-element>`;
```

So instead of just re-drawing only the stuff that changed (a string), your code creates a new TemplateResult and redraws that. This also calls the child element constructor again and causes the text node to go undefined for a moment as you noted. Here is console output added to your impl to show when the constructor and render functions get called for parent and child:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-example-ftlbz7?file=index.js

From inspecting the DOM tree, your example produces this DOM structure:

```
<parent-element>
  #shadow-root
    <div>
      <child-element>
        #shadow-root
          <div>
```

Suppose I need to produce that same DOM structure and have the same text node update in response to the timeout callback, I would probably handle it in the parent render function:

```
_render({ parenttext }) {
  return html`<div><child-element text="${parenttext}"></child-element></div>`;
}
```

which ensures that the child constructor is only called once, and only the data that actually changes gets redrawn.

If I understand correctly, that's how lit-element is designed to be used (expressing an app or element's render as a function of its data). That way we can rely on the browser to just redraw any changes to the data. This should theoretically be faster (altho I haven't tested it).

Code sample here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-example-exrlxw?file=parent-element.js

Lmk what I'm missing from your tests and I can look into it more.

---

Edited to add:

I noticed that overriding `_shouldRender` to prevent the element from rendering with undefined props prevented the element from rendering with undefined props, but it didn't fix `_firstRendered`, which was still firing when props were undefined.

`_firstRendered`, unlike `_didRender`, is not specifically called as a result of `_render`; it is [called from the `ready()` callback](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/fb90e7640777cab01c9eac2006cde558c34b041d/src/lit-element.ts#L106), which is inherited from [Polymer's properties-changed mixin](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/mixins/properties-changed.js). In Polymer, `ready()` fires when the element is added to the DOM. I thought properties should be initialized by then, so this is still pretty weird.

Anyways, this means it is possible to create an element that never renders (i.e `_shouldRender` always returns false), but `_firstRendered` still fires. Lol. Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lit-element-first-rendered?file=index.js.

I'm not honestly sure what to make of any of this. I'll raise an issue on the [lit-element github](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues) when I've read a few more things from the documentation (or you can, if you get there first).

Comment: It's less the implementation and more the side effect that I'm interested in. My example is the simplest version of a much more complicated example in my current code. From what I understand, lit-html is supposed to allow composition of TemplateResults (see https://polymer.github.io/lit-html/guide/writing-templates.html#supported-types). It's just odd that for the first render, the `text` property is set correctly, but then on the second render the child element must be rendered twice with the first time not having the `text` property set correctly. This seems to hinder `_firstRendered()`

Comment: I've updated the issue with a second example based on the lit-html documentation that shows the same behavior.

Comment: Just so you know, I'm looking into this. Thanks for the extra info, it makes a lot more sense now. I'm investigating a few thins - how composition with lit-element should be done, whether it's different when you want to compose with native elements vs custom elements, and so on. I've also noticed that firstRendered doesn't actually depend on a render.

Comment: updated my answer with new info related to my comment above